# Newly added Images not being found Android

Tags: android

I have this code that loads all my images from my external storage with their folder names as `galleries` but I am facing an issue, newly added items are not being found what could be the problem?below is my code:

```
public static Map<String, Album> findGalleries(Context mContext, List<String> paths, long babyId) {
    paths.clear();
    paths.add(FileUtils.getInst().getSystemPhotoPath());
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media._ID, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED };
    Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, projection,
            MediaStore.Images.Media.SIZE + ">?",
            new String[] { "100000" },
            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATE_ADDED + " desc");

    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Map<String, Album> galleries = new HashMap<>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String data = cursor.getString(1);
        if (data.lastIndexOf("/") < 1) {
            continue;
        }
        String sub = data.substring(0, data.lastIndexOf("/"));
        if (!galleries.keySet().contains(sub)) {
            String name = sub.substring(sub.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, sub.length());
            if (!paths.contains(sub)) {
                paths.add(sub);
            }
            galleries.put(sub, new Album(name, sub, new ArrayList<>()));
        }

        galleries.get(sub).getPhotos().add(new PhotoItem(data, (long) (cursor.getInt(2)) * 1000));
    }

    ArrayList<PhotoItem> sysPhotos = FileUtils.getInst().findPicsInDir(
            FileUtils.getInst().getSystemPhotoPath());
    if (!sysPhotos.isEmpty()) {
        galleries.put(FileUtils.getInst().getSystemPhotoPath(), new Album("", FileUtils
                .getInst().getSystemPhotoPath(), sysPhotos));
    } else {
        galleries.remove(FileUtils.getInst().getSystemPhotoPath());
        paths.remove(FileUtils.getInst().getSystemPhotoPath());
    }
    return galleries;
}
```

Comment: Who is adding images? And where? Where are they not found?

Comment: apparently the app shows all images in the phone, except sometimes it fails to show some images